# Why won't this program return anything when run on my computer?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

Currently, I'm attempting (and failing) to read from a file in the context of this homework assignment. The program is supposed to return a list of the number of each word in a separate file when run, yet it returns nothing but a blank screen.  I am making use of the File Reader object  in Java, and using a scanner class to read individual words from that file reader.

I have already tried buffered reader in a similar instance. There is no file not found error, so that can't be it.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileReader inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\[my username]\\Documents\\lorem ipsum.txt");
            System.out.println("Testing.");

            boolean placeholder = false;
            WordBag textfile = new WordBag(2000);
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(inputStream);

            while (scan.hasNext()) {
                Word temp = new Word(scan.next());
                placeholder = textfile.add(temp);
                if (placeholder = false) {
                    System.out.println("Addition failed.");
                }
            }

            while (!textfile.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println(textfile.remove().toString());
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("File not found.");
        }
    }
}
```

- The Word object type has two variables-- One which stores the string, and the second which stores the frequency with which the word appears in the file.
- The WordBag object is essentially an array of these word objects, with some particular methods.

The expected output should be a list of the various words within the file.  However, it is printing nothing whatsoever on the screen.

Edit: It is printing only "Testing." My apologies, I didn't describe the output accurately.

Comment: Please either close your input stream in a `finally` or use a `try-with-resources` to do so automatically. It's not the cause of your problem but it's a bad habit to get into, not closing your streams.

Comment: there should be something on the screen, like `"Testing."` or `"File not found."`. If that's not the case you're not running the code you posted

Comment: `if (placeholder = false)` does not appear to do what you are intending. Use either `if (placeholder == false)` or `if (!placeholder)`

Comment: @Zéychin I'd go with `if (!placeholder)` myself.  I find using `==` with booleans bad style.

Comment: @WJS Likewise, but it appears we're speaking to a student, so I included both for clarity.